# Reading variables from web3 (Documentation is out of date)

Tags: contract-development, nodejs, state-variable

I'm trying to read an `ownersNum` `public uint` from my contract.

I instantiate in node:

```
l = console.log;

var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
let c = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '0x6f4cf704c86da0afeb3cc28cda77f3c69d6e5e0d');

let buyParams = {sender: '0x08df113cf3cec557397e471452d38b84d912e4be',value: 1000000000000000};

l(c.methods.buyKey.call(buyParams));
let on = c.methods.ownersNum;
l(on.call());
```

The last log prints out a huge function:

```
{ [Function: Contract]
  setProvider: [Function],
  defaultAccount: null,
  defaultBlock: 'latest',
  currentProvider: [Getter/Setter],
  _requestManager:
   RequestManager {
     provider: HttpProvider { host: 'http://localhost:8545', timeout: 0, connected: false },
     providers:
      { WebsocketProvider: [Function: WebsocketProvider],
        HttpProvider: [Function: HttpProvider],
        IpcProvider: [Function: IpcProvider] },
     subscriptions: {} },
  givenProvider: null,
  providers:
   { WebsocketProvider: [Function: WebsocketProvider],
     HttpProvider: [Function: HttpProvider],
     IpcProvider: [Function: IpcProvider] },
  _provider: HttpProvider { host: 'http://localhost:8545', timeout: 0, connected: false },
  BatchRequest: [Function: bound Batch],
  extend:
   { [Function: ex]
     formatters:
      { inputDefaultBlockNumberFormatter: [Function: inputDefaultBlockNumberFormatter],
        inputBlockNumberFormatter: [Function: inputBlockNumberFormatter],
        inputCallFormatter: [Function: inputCallFormatter],
        inputTransactionFormatter: [Function: inputTransactionFormatter],
        inputAddressFormatter: [Function: inputAddressFormatter],
        inputPostFormatter: [Function: inputPostFormatter],
        inputLogFormatter: [Function: inputLogFormatter],
        inputSignFormatter: [Function: inputSignFormatter],
        outputBigNumberFormatter: [Function: outputBigNumberFormatter],
        outputTransactionFormatter: [Function: outputTransactionFormatter],
        outputTransactionReceiptFormatter: [Function: outputTransactionReceiptFormatter],
        outputBlockFormatter: [Function: outputBlockFormatter],
        outputLogFormatter: [Function: outputLogFormatter],
        outputPostFormatter: [Function: outputPostFormatter],
        outputSyncingFormatter: [Function: outputSyncingFormatter] },
     utils:
      { _fireError: [Function: _fireError],
        _jsonInterfaceMethodToString: [Function: _jsonInterfaceMethodToString],
        randomHex: [Function: randomHex],
        _: [Object],
        BN: [Object],
        isBN: [Function: isBN],
        isBigNumber: [Function: isBigNumber],
        isHex: [Function: isHex],
        isHexStrict: [Function: isHexStrict],
        sha3: [Object],
        keccak256: [Object],
        soliditySha3: [Function: soliditySha3],
        isAddress: [Function: isAddress],
        checkAddressChecksum: [Function: checkAddressChecksum],
        toChecksumAddress: [Function: toChecksumAddress],
        toHex: [Function: toHex],
        toBN: [Function: toBN],
        bytesToHex: [Function: bytesToHex],
        hexToBytes: [Function: hexToBytes],
        hexToNumberString: [Function: hexToNumberString],
        hexToNumber: [Function: hexToNumber],
        toDecimal: [Function: hexToNumber],
        numberToHex: [Function: numberToHex],
        fromDecimal: [Function: numberToHex],
        hexToUtf8: [Function: hexToUtf8],
        hexToString: [Function: hexToUtf8],
        toUtf8: [Function: hexToUtf8],
        utf8ToHex: [Function: utf8ToHex],
        stringToHex: [Function: utf8ToHex],
        fromUtf8: [Function: utf8ToHex],
        hexToAscii: [Function: hexToAscii],
        toAscii: [Function: hexToAscii],
        asciiToHex: [Function: asciiToHex],
        fromAscii: [Function: asciiToHex],
        unitMap: [Object],
        toWei: [Function: toWei],
        fromWei: [Function: fromWei],
        padLeft: [Function: leftPad],
        leftPad: [Function: leftPad],
        padRight: [Function: rightPad],
        rightPad: [Function: rightPad],
        toTwosComplement: [Function: toTwosComplement] },
     Method: [Function: Method] },
  _ethAccounts:
   Accounts {
     currentProvider: [Getter/Setter],
     _requestManager: RequestManager { provider: [Object], providers: [Object], subscriptions: {} },
     givenProvider: null,
     providers:
      { WebsocketProvider: [Function: WebsocketProvider],
        HttpProvider: [Function: HttpProvider],
        IpcProvider: [Function: IpcProvider] },
     _provider: HttpProvider { host: 'http://localhost:8545', timeout: 0, connected: false },
     setProvider: [Function],
     _ethereumCall:
      { getId: [Object],
        getGasPrice: [Object],
        getTransactionCount: [Object] },
     wallet:
      Wallet {
        _accounts: [Circular],
        length: 0,
        defaultKeyName: 'web3js_wallet' } } }
{ call: { [Function: bound _executeMethod] request: [Function: bound _executeMethod] },
  send: { [Function: bound _executeMethod] request: [Function: bound _executeMethod] },
  encodeABI: [Function: bound _encodeMethodABI],
  estimateGas: [Function: bound _executeMethod],
  arguments: [],
  _method:
   { constant: false,
     inputs: [],
     name: 'buyKey',
     outputs: [],
     payable: true,
     stateMutability: 'payable',
     type: 'function',
     signature: '0xe95db6f9' },
  _parent:
   Contract {
     currentProvider: [Getter/Setter],
     _requestManager: RequestManager { provider: [Object], providers: [Object], subscriptions: {} },
     givenProvider: null,
     providers:
      { WebsocketProvider: [Function: WebsocketProvider],
        HttpProvider: [Function: HttpProvider],
        IpcProvider: [Function: IpcProvider] },
     _provider: HttpProvider { host: 'http://localhost:8545', timeout: 0, connected: false },
     setProvider: [Function],
     BatchRequest: [Function: bound Batch],
     extend:
      { [Function: ex]
        formatters: [Object],
        utils: [Object],
        Method: [Function: Method] },
     clearSubscriptions: [Function],
     options: { address: [Getter/Setter], jsonInterface: [Getter/Setter] },
     defaultAccount: [Getter/Setter],
     defaultBlock: [Getter/Setter],
     methods:
      { owners: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0x025e7c27': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'owners(uint256)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        ownersNum: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0x195fa903': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'ownersNum()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        buyKey: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0xe95db6f9': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'buyKey()': [Function: bound _createTxObject] },
     events: { allEvents: [Function: bound ] },
     _address: '0x6f4Cf704c86DA0afeB3cC28Cda77F3c69D6E5E0d',
     _jsonInterface: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  _ethAccounts: undefined }
{ call: { [Function: bound _executeMethod] request: [Function: bound _executeMethod] },
  send: { [Function: bound _executeMethod] request: [Function: bound _executeMethod] },
  encodeABI: [Function: bound _encodeMethodABI],
  estimateGas: [Function: bound _executeMethod],
  arguments: [],
  _method:
   { constant: true,
     inputs: [],
     name: 'ownersNum',
     outputs: [ [Object] ],
     payable: false,
     stateMutability: 'view',
     type: 'function',
     signature: '0x195fa903' },
  _parent:
   Contract {
     currentProvider: [Getter/Setter],
     _requestManager: RequestManager { provider: [Object], providers: [Object], subscriptions: {} },
     givenProvider: null,
     providers:
      { WebsocketProvider: [Function: WebsocketProvider],
        HttpProvider: [Function: HttpProvider],
        IpcProvider: [Function: IpcProvider] },
     _provider: HttpProvider { host: 'http://localhost:8545', timeout: 0, connected: false },
     setProvider: [Function],
     BatchRequest: [Function: bound Batch],
     extend:
      { [Function: ex]
        formatters: [Object],
        utils: [Object],
        Method: [Function: Method] },
     clearSubscriptions: [Function],
     options: { address: [Getter/Setter], jsonInterface: [Getter/Setter] },
     defaultAccount: [Getter/Setter],
     defaultBlock: [Getter/Setter],
     methods:
      { owners: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0x025e7c27': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'owners(uint256)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        ownersNum: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0x195fa903': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'ownersNum()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        buyKey: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0xe95db6f9': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'buyKey()': [Function: bound _createTxObject] },
     events: { allEvents: [Function: bound ] },
     _address: '0x6f4Cf704c86DA0afeB3cC28Cda77F3c69D6E5E0d',
     _jsonInterface: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  _ethAccounts: undefined }
```

which is unexpected.

In Truffle, instantiating and calling this variable returns a map with the correct value, an integer, inside of it.

I am also confused about buyParams which is a `payable`. I can't call `sendTransaction`, method not found, but I can use call..

How do I read a state variable?

Comment: l(c.methods.buyKey.call(buyParams));  -> l(c.methods.buyKey(byuParams).call({options));

Comment: where options is optional?

Comment: "invalid parameters for buyKey, got 1 expected 0

Comment: Check this: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call

Comment: I try let buyParams = {sender: '0x08df113cf3cec557397e471452d38b84d912e4be',value: 1000000000000000};

c.methods.buyKey().call(buyParams);

c.methods.ownersNum.call(function(a,b) {
  l(a);
  l(b);
});
, nothing prints @Andromelus

Comment: Ah, I see I need to use the Promises! Thank you. The original documentation was not clear. Params needs FROM - Truffle & Solidity use "SENDER" but web3 uses FROM

Comment: Yeah, documentation is a bit confusing sometimes. I will write a proper answer :)

Comment: Thanks @Andromelus . I submitted 1 edit to your answer to change .call to .send to be explicit about sending transaction. I also added a couple issues on ethereum wiki github to address incorrect documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using web3js, you need to pass the options in the call function and use a promise or a callback to handle the response, for exemple:

```
    contract.methods.buyKey().call({from: 0x, <somemore params if required>},
function(error, result){
    if(error)
    {
    do stuff
    } else {
    //your result is the result variable
    }

    })
```

With a promise:

```
contract.methods.buyKey().call({from: 0x, <somemore params if required>})
.then(function(result){
console.log(result);
});
```

Edit: Someone proposed an edit with send instead of call. Here we are talking about reading a variable from a constant function. So we need a call because it does not change the EVM (unless the OP forgot to specify it, and then, yes, we need a transaction)